# Smarty : Use {block} in included files?

Tags: smarty

I'm mainly using twig as template engine for my projects. But for a project i need to use Smarty. So i'm new with this template engine. As far i know, in Twig, we can use embedded templates. Here the definition of an embedded template from the Twig documentation:

> The embed tag combines the behavior of include and extends. It allows you to include
> another template's contents, just like include does. But it also
> allows you to override any block defined inside the included template,
> like when extending a template. Think of an embedded template as a
> "micro layout skeleton".

So, it's like including a subtemplate but the included subtemplate have different block tags reusables in the parent template.

Does something equivalent exists with Smarty?

I was thinking something like:

***parent.tpl***

```
<html>{block name='title'} {/block}</html>
<body>
{block name="content"} {/block}
</body>
```

***main.tpl***

```
{extends "parent.tpl"}
{block 'title'}my main page{/block}
{block 'content'}
    {include 'subtemplate.inc.tpl'}
    {block 'top_include'}...{/block}
{/block}
```

***subtemplate.inc.tpl***

```
{block name='top_include'}...{/block}
```

I know this is not working. But i'm looking for a way to accomplish my goal.In fact i want to reuse a modal component. Instead of rewrite the html code of the modal in each place where it will be used, i need to write the code once and call it from everywhere in my templates but changing only some small parts of the modal component (the title and some buttons).

Comment: Please check the documentation: https://smarty-php.github.io/smarty/stable/api/inheritance/ or https://www.smarty.net/inheritance. I think you can do it via variables inside blocks or calling a function (Smarty 'call' feature).